# How to disable the "Post Lock/Edit Lock"?

Tags: wp-admin, heartbeat-api

I want to disable this just for one Post Type, as it doesn't really matters if there's another user editing it (the main content editing area is Ajaxified and non-admins can only see that).

[image]

I looked at the core functions but couldn't find an entry point. From the function [`wp_set_post_lock`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L1178) I'm guessing that I'd have to intercept the `get_post_meta`, but is there an *official* way to do it?

And there's a [second lock](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L667) that doesn't seem to be affected by the filter `wp_check_post_lock_window` ([as shown by birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120179/how-to-disable-the-post-lock-edit-lock/120187#120187), here in an Answer). I've tried `remove_filter( 'heartbeat_received', 'wp_refresh_post_lock', 10, 3 );` at various points but it keeps beating without respecting `remove_filter`.

[image]

Comment: I've added a clarification about the motives, and it brings a solution to mind: showing this content to non-admins in another screen. But would be nice to know a proper hook to `post_lock` nonetheless.

Answer (score 11):

As an addition to ***@birgire*** answer…

### Findings

[`register_post_type()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_post_type_support/) allows to register a post type support, which can as well be [done later on using `add_post_type_support()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_post_type_support/). And that can get checked against even later using the all mighty [`post_type_supports( $cpt, $feat )`](http://queryposts.com/function/post_type_supports/).

### A general mini plugin that adds a new feature

Now the following (mu-)plugin checks for a new kind of post type support that disables the post lock feature. It's named `disabled_post_lock`.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' );
/** Plugin Name: (#120179) Maybe Disable Post Type Support */

add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'wpse120179MaybeDisablePostLock' );
function wpse120179MaybeDisablePostLock()
{
    if ( post_type_supports( get_current_screen()->post_type, 'disabled_post_lock' ) )
        add_filter( 'wp_check_post_lock_window', '__return_false' );
}
```

### One plugin per CPT

Then we can easily add mini plugins to disable post type support for our own or third party plugins (saving us some bandwidth and DB size in the user meta table):

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' );
/** Plugin Name: (#120179) Disable Post Type Support for "Beer" Posts */

add_action( 'init', function()
{
    add_post_type_support( 'beer', 'disabled_post_lock' );
} );
```

As soon as the second plugin is activated our ***beer*** post type has no more post lock. This should work nice and is easily revertable through the plugins admin screen.

### Disabling the heartbeat API

Extending the plugin to disable the hearbeat API as well:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' );
/** Plugin Name: (#120179) Maybe Disable Post Type Support */

add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'wpse120179MaybeDisablePostLock' );
function wpse120179MaybeDisablePostLock()
{
    if ( post_type_supports( get_current_screen()->post_type, 'disabled_post_lock' ) )
    {
        add_filter( 'wp_check_post_lock_window', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'heartbeat_settings', function( $settings )
        {
            return wp_parse_args( [ 'autostart' => false ], $settings );
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really *classy* solution, how would you handle the `admin-ajax.php` part (Q updated and A added)?

Comment: @brasofilo I added an edit to disable the Heartbeat API completely. Not sure how you want to handle that, but you can still run the heartbeat API in plugins by using `wp.heartbeat.start();` in your JavaScript.

Comment: it's great idea using the `post_type_supports` to handle this for each custom post type, I wish I could give you more upvotes ;-)

Answer (score 7):

To remove the *edit-lock* popup window, you could try:

```
add_filter( 'wp_check_post_lock_window', '__return_zero' );
```

I'm not sure if this is the way to go, but I checked the source of `wp_check_post_lock()`
and there we have these lines:

```
...cut...

$time_window = apply_filters( 'wp_check_post_lock_window', 120 );

if ( $time && $time > time() - $time_window && $user != get_current_user_id() )
    return $user;
return false;

...cut...
```

so the idea is to change `$time_window` so the `if` condition is `false`.

### Update:

To apply this on the `edit.php` screen, with the custom post type `beer` for example:

```
function wpse_120179()
{
    if( 'beer' === get_current_screen()->post_type )
        add_filter( 'wp_check_post_lock_window', '__return_zero' );

}
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'wpse_120179' );
```

And then we can add:

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'wpse_120179' );
```

to remove it for the `post.php` screen as well.

### More digging ...

The function  `_admin_notice_post_locked()` is [defined](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7/src/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L1217) just below the `wp_set_post_lock()` function. It contains these lines:

```
...cut...
if ( ! apply_filters( 'show_post_locked_dialog', true, $post, $user ) )
    return;
...cut...
```

so one can also try the `show_post_locked_dialog` filter:

```
add_filter( 'show_post_locked_dialog', 'wpse_120179_close_dialog', 99, 3 );

function wpse_120179_close_dialog( $show, $post, $user )
{
    if( 'beer' === $post->post_type )
        return FALSE;

    return $show;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use `__return_false()` instead as the first check for `$time` just sums up as a `bool TRUE`?

Comment: ok maybe, but I'm not sure how to set `$time` to `false` so I went for `$time_window` instead ...

Answer (score 3):

The final combination I've ended using is

```
# Takes care of the message "Someone else is editing this"
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function()
{
    if( 'beer' === get_current_screen()->post_type )
        add_filter( 'wp_check_post_lock_window', '__return_false' );
});

# Takes care of post.php and the "User has taken over" message
add_filter( 'show_post_locked_dialog', function( $bool, $post, $user )
{
    if( 'beer' === $post->post_type )
        return false;
    return $bool;
}, 
10, 3 );
```

but if anyone has another take, I'd love to hear, as I'm not really understanding the whole picture of filters available.

> Previously, using `load-edit.php` + `load-post.php`, I had to remove
>   the filter `wp_refresh_post_lock` with:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'admin_init', function()
> {
>     if( !defined('DOING_AJAX') || !isset( $_POST['screen_id'] ) || 'beer' !== $_POST['screen_id'] )
>         return;
>
>     remove_filter( 'heartbeat_received', 'wp_refresh_post_lock', 10 );
> });
> ```
>
> but loading at every `admin_init` doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: Please use `get_current_screen()->post_type` instead. [Here's a nice plugin](https://github.com/wecodemore/current-admin-info) called ***Current Admin Info*** to assist you with retrieving such info.

Comment: @kaiser, my intention here is to block the heartbeat for Ajax, maybe I should add some `DOING_AJAX` check... And as I understand it, Ajax has no `global $current_screen` (returned by `get_current_screen()`).

Comment: Ah, maybe. Dunno at the moment. Btw, there's [`wp_is_autosave()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_is_post_autosave/) - not sure if that accounts to any of those actions.

Comment: I wonder if `add_filter( 'show_post_locked_dialog', '__return_false' );`, from the function `_admin_notice_post_locked()`, is of any help?

Comment: @birgire, nope, didn't work. I'm thinking that's not possible to stop `wp_ajax_heartbeat()` (wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php) using the chain `load-$hook` -> `get_current_something()`. . . . . Also, there are 3 hooks in that function, but I'm not being able to stop the beat using them (and they have `$screen_id`, which matches the post type.

Comment: It feels like trying to give WordPress a heart attack ... ;-) But does it work if you add/remove the filters directly (thus for all cpt?)

Comment: @birgire, yes sir, that's the one that stops the beat :) Wee gave OL'WP a heart attack! The filter also takes `$post` and `$user` as arguments, it was the final nail. Please, add it to your Answer.

Comment: ok great, poor old WP ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the final solution that works for me. :

```
function my_remove_post_locked() {
    $current_post_type = get_current_screen()->post_type;   

    // Disable locking for page, post and some custom post type
    $post_types_arr = array(
        'page',
        'post',
        'custom_post_type'
    );

    if(in_array($current_post_type, $post_types_arr)) {
        add_filter( 'show_post_locked_dialog', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'wp_check_post_lock_window', '__return_false' );
        wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');
    }
}

add_action('load-edit.php', 'my_remove_post_locked');
add_action('load-post.php', 'my_remove_post_locked');
```