# Why are simple updates to wp_postmeta's "_edit_lock" so slow?

Tags: mysql, post-meta

In our MySQL slow query log, the cumulatively slowest query is a simple update to wp_postmeta.  Here's an example:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
  SET `meta_value` = '1392835505:386'
  WHERE `post_id` = 94705 AND `meta_key` = '_edit_lock';
```

Relevant details on our setup:

- MySQL slow query time set to 1s
- wp_postmeta's storage engine is InnoDB
- Running within a large Multisite installation with tens of thousands of posts on the main WP blog (where these slow queries are occurring)
- High activity in the WP admin area (lots of writers/editors working concurrently, but generally on their own (not others') content)
- Low activity on the public side of WP (not actually serving up content from the main blog)
- The slow queries seem to all be using the "_edit_lock" key; queries of the same format (that use a key other than "_edit_lock") do not seem to be slow.

Why is it that this is the slowest query on our system?  Does it have something to do with WP's specific use of "edit locks"?

Thanks! :)

---

Update: Output from mysqlsla below:

```
______________________________________________________________________ 001 ___
Count         : 606  (16.83%)
Time          : 2257.760468 s total, 3.725677 s avg, 1.00512 s to 84.645869 s max  (20.60%)
  95% of Time : 1355.289277 s total, 2.357025 s avg, 1.00512 s to 12.343604 s max
Lock Time (s) : 182.502 ms total, 301 μs avg, 29 μs to 157.542 ms max  (0.21%)
  95% of Lock : 22.882 ms total, 40 μs avg, 29 μs to 57 μs max
Rows sent     : 0 avg, 0 to 0 max  (0.00%)
Rows examined : 1 avg, 1 to 2 max  (0.00%)
Database      : xxx_wp
Users         :
        xxx_wp@localhost  : 98.84% (599) of query, 51.03% (1837) of all users
        yyy_wp@localhost  : 1.16% (7) of query, 0.94% (34) of all users

Query abstract:
SET timestamp=N; UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'S' WHERE post_id = N AND meta_key = 'S';

Query sample:
SET timestamp=1392835506;
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '1392835505:386' WHERE `post_id` = 94705 AND `meta_key` = '_edit_lock';
```

Comment: How many results do you get for `SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_edit_lock'`; ?

Comment: Thanks for your question, adrian7!  There are 33k rows matching your query.  I'm not familiar with WP's usage of the '_edit_lock' meta key.  Is this abnormal?

Comment: it's not abnormal, wordpress uses it to alert users when they are trying to edit the same post/page. I suggest you delete all of the _edit_locks from the wp_postmeta, obviously when there's no one editing and check after any performance improvements. (BTW make a backup first).

Comment: Does it also take a huge amount of time when you just `SELECT` this entry? Like `SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = 94705 AND `meta_key` = '_edit_lock';`?

Comment: @fischi: That query seems to take from 45-50ms, at least in the testing I just did a few moments ago.  However, it's possible that it would occasionally take a very long time (e.g. up to 84 seconds, as shown in the mysqlsla output included in the question).  I'll run a new round of slow query analysis to see if any of my recent changes to our configuration have affected the queries.

Comment: It appears that we're still getting slow queries of this type... The strangest thing is that our server overall is relatively idle.  We're on an 8-CPU VPS with a current load of 0.27 0.51 0.66 and a consistent InnoDB cache hit rate of 100%.  I think most of us would agree that this is likely not an issue with the actual SQL generated by Wordpress, but rather, the underlying architecture and how it translates to the database (MySQL).  There seems to be something strange going on here that is deeper than just SQL query optimization and such...

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28382 could be related. Decreasing the query cache might help.

Comment: Hmm... Could be.  That bug is a duplicate of http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21074, which appears to be closed and included in version 5.1.23.  We are running 5.1.73. :/  Regardless, it's still worth a shot - I suppose I can experiment with different cache/buffer sizes to see if there is an apparent connection.  Either way, this issue certainly isn't grinding our system to a halt; it's more of a yellow flag.  Perhaps the fact that this is coming up is due to our overabundance of resources and eagerness with slow query hunting and elimination... ?  Still, something odd is definitely going on.

Comment: (aka, perhaps, like you suggest, throwing more resources at the issue IS the source of the problem itself...)

Comment: First on the all times you need check a your server configurations for performance, and best uses. Wordpress with this a lot of data, structure will be very slow itselft. Sometimes you get a mysql crash or other server things. If you make a one people at the time on your server, page, that this will create a quick job. Problem is on server side, not in Wordpress. Take your mysql on other VSP and page on other, make a cloud services, ssd disk on server, put more RAM memory on server. Than you can objective make a good testing of query requests.

Answer (score 5):

the _edit_lock is generated each time you edit a post or page. it consist the timecode and the user. so WordPress is knowing who is currently editing it.

```
meta_id     post_id     meta_key    meta_value
9           5           _edit_lock  1388386997:1
```

if you manipulate it WordPress reacts somehow sensitive ...I tried to fetch how many seconds somebody worked on a post. All the time it broke my database loading time.

As you said you running this on a large multisite. Don't know how many users write posts there, but it definitely could break the RAM of the server if to many people edit a post at the same time.

A solution could be:
get rid of _edit_lock

[How to disable the "Post Lock/Edit Lock"?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120179/how-to-disable-the-post-lock-edit-lock)

Normally WordPress should have the "_edit_lock" one per Post. Some databases have the problem generating them every time.

Like this guy
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-remove-_edit_lock-_edit_last-from-wp_postmeta

His solution was to delete them all.
To speed it up you can delete them all every night at 3 o'clock in phpMyAdmin with

```
DELETE FROM `yourdb`.`wp_postmeta` WHERE `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_edit_lock'
```

might be you find a cron job doing exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
    SET `meta_value` = concat(unix_timestamp(),':386')  
    WHERE `post_id`  = 94705 
      AND `meta_key` = '_edit_lock';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok probably, the easy way is use WP method.

`update_post_meta($post_id, '_edit_lock', time().':'.$user_id);`